# How to test nested React components using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

How to test nested React components using Jest?

**BasicInfo.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import FormComponent from '@/components/FormComponent';
    import Styles from './Style.scss';
    import {basicInfoForm} from './BasicInfoForm'


    class BasicInfo extends Component {


            componentDidMount = ()=>{
                this.props.form.setFieldsValue({status:true})
                }

        render() {
            const menu = [
                {

                  title: 'Basic Info',
                  key:'general',
                  formWrapperId:'address-form-wrapper',
                  key:'define',

                },
                {
                  title: 'Normal Info',
                  key:'economy',
                  formWrapperId:'address-form-wrapper',
                  key:'undefine'

                }
              ];


              return (
                <div id="basic-info-container">
                  <p id="basic-info-desc"> {formatMessage({id:description[mode]})}</p>
                  {menu.map(formRow=>(
                    <div key={formRow.key}>
                      <div id={`${formRow.key}-info-subtitle`}>{formRow.title}</div>
                      <div id={formRow.formWrapperId}>
                        <FormComponent
                          formName={`${title}_form`}
                          form={form}
                          item={formRow.item}
                          formItems={formRow.formItems}
                          onChangeEventRef={formRow.onChangeInput}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              );

        }







        }


    export default BasicInfo;
```

**BasicInfo.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import BasicInfo from './BasicInfoPage';
import FormComponent from '@/components/FormComponent';

describe('should checking Basic Info Page', () => {

    test('should check values', () => {
        const menu = [
            {
              title: 'Basic Info',
              key:'general',
              formWrapperId:'address-form-wrapper',
              key:'define'

            },
            {
              title: 'Normal Info',
              key:'economy',
              formWrapperId:'address-form-wrapper',
              key:'undefine'

            }
          ];

          const wrapper = shallow(<BasicInfo mock={menu} />);
          expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()


    })


})
```

Here I am mapping menu array and calling child form component to get the stuff. So please suggest how to write test cases for this type of scenario.

**I am getting below error while running the npm test**

> Page checking › Wrapper RENDERER snapshot
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'formItem' of undefined
>
>   123 |       const translation = 'agencyForm.agencyDetails.basicDetails';
>   124 |       const { title , form, mode, agencyDetailModel}  = this.props
> > 125 |       const {formItem} = agencyDetailModel;
>       |              ^
>   126 |       const {description} = this.state
>   127 |
>   128 |       const BasicFormRows =[
> at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/AgencyManagement/Agencies/AgencyDetails/BasicInfo/BasicInfoPage.test.js:13:19)
>
>     (node:18876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> ```
>
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
>   which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
>   unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
>   `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
>   https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 1)
>           (node:18876) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I want to test the component whether the data is correct or not in test file

Comment: So... *did you try that*? Where's the test part of your [mre]?

Comment: ya i used shallow but i didn't get the proper things, I am new to Jest also

  const wrapper = shallow(<BasicInfo mock={menu} />);
   console.log("what is wraper", wrapper);

Comment: Please [edit] the question, then, and with a more useful description of the problem than *"didn't get the proper things"*.

Comment: yes , please check once i added

Comment: The problem seems to be that you haven't tried anything. Maybe start there.

Comment: Yes, I tried but I deleted could you please tell how to test those attribute

Comment: Ditch the emoji, and please note that this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. I'd recommend reading the docs for the tools you're using.

Comment: Ya ok. Please suggest how to proceed further my question?

Comment: *"I'd recommend reading the docs for the tools you're using."* I see no point in responding further.

Comment: Yes, please recheck once. I modified

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to match the code you've posted. Also the BasicInfo component doesn't seem to use the "mock" prop you're passing.